# Mac drive in use, understanding lsof

Tags: mount, osx, macintosh, lsof

I am trying to repair permissions on my external HD. I cannot empty my trash when it is plugged in, because I get a bunch of "such file is in use". I read online that this might be resolved by repairing permissions on the drive. I am currently unable to unmount the drive because it is in use the second I restart or unplug and replug it in. I used `lsof` to see what is using it but I am unable to understand this and can't seem to find a clear guide to learn what this means. The output is below:

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mds      59 root   23r   DIR    1,9     1701    5 /Volumes/SEAGATE
mds      59 root   31r   DIR    1,9     1701    5 /Volumes/SEAGATE
```

Command

```
ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|mds)'
```

Output

```
PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
660   ??  Ss     0:12.49 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds
673   ??  Ss     0:08.68 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds_stores
```

Command

```
/usr/bin/sudo kill 660
```

Output

```
//new line$
```

Command

```
sudo lsof /dev/disk2s2
```

Output

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mds     1599 root   11r   DIR    1,8     1764    5 /Volumes/SEAGATE
```

In that order

If I run the bash file several times in a row I can get

```
PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
1737   ??  Ss     0:00.69 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds
```

But the drive is still locked by mds

Just to show that the exception was added, here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add to your question the output of: `df ` and of `lsof /dev/disk…` where `/dev/disk…` is the name of your external disk `SEAGATE`. I don't talk here of its mount point which is `/Volumes/SEAGATE` .

Comment: added, but df would only allow for the mount point

Comment: Now run `lsof /dev/disk2s2`.

Comment: I did run that in the image above? It returns the same thing, which is nothing

Comment: Now that you are sure nothing is reading your external disk, you can unmount it forcibly with: `umount -f /dev/disk2s2`. Next open `Disk Utility` select it, click [Verify Disk], if necessary [Repair Disk].

Comment: The did it! Thanks so much for you patients and help!

Comment: Don't forget step 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Too fast diagnosis

> I read online that this might be resolved by repairing permission on the drive.

Unfortunatly, from the description of your problem, this is wrong. What need to be repaired is the filesystem on your external disk `SEAGATE`.

### Analysis of `lsof`

The output of your `lsof` command tells that the command `mds` (1st column) is actually reading your filesystem `/volumes/SEAGATE` (last colume).
To learn more about this fantastic command, just read the manual which is
coming with MacOS X:

```
man lsof
```

`mds` is a MacOS X server in charge of providing an access to the metadata
of all your filesystems. Its most important clients are `Finder` and `Spotlight`.

If you can't eject your external disk, this is legitimate and due to `mds` still reading it. If you nonetheless extract it, you will surely corrupt its filesystem.

### Free and repair the filesystem

Now that it is corrupted, here is how to fix this.

1. Open `System Preferences > Spotlight`
   select `Privacy` window
   and add (<kbd>+</kbd>) your SEAGATE external disk to stop `Spotlight`
   to try to index it.
2. If `mds` is still running:

   ```
   ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|mds)'
   ```

   You will have to kill it:

   ```
   _pid_to_kill=`ps ax | egrep '[ /]mds' | awk '{print $1}'`
   if [ "${_pid_to_kill}" ] ; then
       echo "${_pid_to_kill}" | while read _pid ; do
           /usr/bin/sudo kill ${_pid}
       done
   fi
   ```

   Check with `lsof` that your `SEAGATE` disk is now free:

   ```
   lsof /Volumes/SEAGATE
   ```

   If this is OK, GOTO 4.
3. If killing `mds` doesn't free `/Volumes/SEAGATE` then there is another
   process accessing this filesystem through `mds`. (This might be an anti-virus or a crapware. And this is quite another size of investigation).
   In this case, the fast path will be to stop `launchd` from starting `mds`.

   Proceed as follows:

   ```
   cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
   /usr/bin/sudo launchctl unload com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
   ```

   Check that you don't have anymore `mds` process:

   ```
   ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|mds)'
   ```

   Check with `lsof` that your `SEAGATE` disk is now free:

   ```
   lsof /Volumes/SEAGATE
   ```

   This should be OK, GOTO 4.
4. Start `Disk Utility`
   and check your disk `SEAGATE`.
   I suspect that some repairs will be needed.
   In this case repair it.

   Eject it, and check that you don't have any more any "file in use"
   error message.
5. Open `System Preferences > Spotlight`
   select `Privacy` window
   and remove (<kbd>-</kbd>) your SEAGATE external disk to permit `Spotlight`
   to index it.
6. If you passed strep 3. where you had to stop `launchd` from starting `mds` you will have to enable this function back (otherwise a lot of thing managing your filesystem will fail).

   Proceed as follows:

   ```
   cd /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
   /usr/bin/sudo launchctl load com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
   ```

Comment: I did as you suggested, lsof now returns nothing but the drive is still unmountable due to disk utility claiming its still in use. Even ps ax | egrep '[ /](PID|mds)' returns nothing. You have been so very helpful. I don't know if you have any other suggestions? But you have answered the original question, this is just a matter of finding what is using the drive.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Spotlight is indexing this drive. There could be a problem that is causing Spotlight to hang up and constantly pound this drive.

The `mds` process is the metadata server. Try killing this process and then tell spotlight to not index this drive.

To disable spotlight indexing go to System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy and add the disk to the exclusions list. You might have to kill `mds` and restart it to get spotlight to stop the indexing.

Not sure that this is your problem, but it would be a good place to start.

Comment: So I kill mds and it just shows up with a new PID. IT WONT STAY DEAD!

Comment: Yeah that shouldn't be a huge problem, just make sure that you modify the Spotlight configs then kill it and let it respawn. It should not show up in the `lsof` command anymore if things are correctly set up.